# How to handle large request when one API is calling another API in spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api

I have built a restful API that needs to access a DB and call another API internally. The internal API calling sometimes throws "Internal Server Error" while I am continuously sending requests to the main API. Especially, after sending 2000 HTTP requests, the internal API fails to handle requests. After some time that becomes stable. How can I handle this situation in Spring Boot so that continuously calling to the main API doesn't make the internal API calling unresponsive? I need to send more or less 50,000 requests to the main API.

Comment: Is that 50k _concurrent_ requests? In what time frame? - What you might need to think about is scaling out, e.g. running multiple instances of your APIs to handle that. Alternatively you might need to rebuild your API or at least employ patterns like [bulkhead](https://medium.com/geekculture/bulkhead-pattern-microservice-design-pattern-9e30d414a0fd) or [circuit breaker](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html). Some form of caching might also help but it's hard to tell without having way more info - and that might be totally out of scope for SO.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a 50k sequential request as per the client's requirement.  The time frame is 2.5 hours. The patterns you have mentioned will be helpful to me.

Comment: How long does it take to fulfil a request like those? 50k in 2.5 hours (or 9000 seconds) is only about 5.5 to 6 requests per second on average - this is fairly low. You might need to also address the way requests are fulfilled.